# Android: Bundle.toString() and then create a Bundle from String

Tags: android, bundle

I'm trying to do the following:

```
// I have a Bundle and convert it to string
Bundle _bundle;
// Meanwhile I put intergers, booleans etc in _bundle
String _strBundle = _bundle.toString();
```

Later in my code I need to create a Bundle from _strBundle. How do I do that? So far I couldn't find any information on this. Of course I don't wish to parse _strBundle myself and hope that the fremawork already provides a String2Bundle sort of a functionality.

Comment: you have a Bundle in the _bundle.So why do you need Bundle from _strBundle.

Comment: At some point in time I need to create a Bundle from a string. It's long to explain why I need this.

Comment: `_strBundle` could be passed on to some other piece of code, from where `_bundle` may not be visible. Use cases include sending it across some channel which supports string data but not Java objects (such as some RPC mechanism or a network connection), or storing it to a file.

Comment: I answered the question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65711106/6884103 Happy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way for the framework to know what is stored in your string. The same pattern could have possible interpretations (string, boolean, integer) and so i don't think that that actually even makes sense.

In fact i can't imagine why you would need to do it. You already have the bundle in the first place. I suggest you keep the original bundle and use it when you need it or make the parse of the string and create the bundle yourself (which won't be an easy task if you want to cover all the possibilities).

Comment: Yes indeed, possible interpretations are possible. I have the impression that String-to-Bundle is not supported by the framework. If it was possible I had a terrific software architecture design in my mind, but I have to revise it now I think :-)

Comment: I'm glad i could help. Do you know about the principle of accepting answers here by clicking on the checkbox outline beside your favorite answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass data as String to another place, it's better to use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) it's very simple to create JSONObject from String and vice versa. And it's too similar to Bundle class!

```
json = new JSONObject(str);
str = json.toString();
```

Also, You can pass it as String parameter with Intent or the other method as String.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done by first converting the Bundle to ByteArray as per in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680028/3286489

Then from the ByteArray, we could convert it to Base64String (`import android.util.Base64;`) using

```
String stringBundle = Base64.encodeToString(bundleByteArray, 0)
```

For completeness, to convert from String back to bundleByteArray, you could use

```
byte[] bundleByteArray = Base64.decode(stringBundle, 0)
```

Then from byteArray, convert it back to Bundle as per in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680028/3286489

Answer (score -2):

Here is a use case:

If your application uses a shared singleton, you might want to pass that
from intent to intent, rather than rely on Android's lazy mechanism to
make shared thread data available in another thread.

By converting the Bundle to a string, and passing that:

```
    Bundle singleton_bundle = new Bundle();
    if (onSaveInstanceState(singleton_bundle)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "SHARE: pass singleton_bundle to next Activity");
        String mysingleton = singleton_bundle.toString();
        if (mysingleton != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "put MYSINGLETON="+mysingleton);
            intent.putExtra("MYSINGLETON", mysingleton);
        }
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

the new Activity can receive the singleton bundle (in String form), but unfortunately can not easily convert that back into a Bundle to be decoded.  This is what I'd like to do:

```
    Intent currentIntent = activity.getIntent();
    String mysingleton = currentIntent.getExtras().getString("MYSINGLETON");
    if (mysingleton != null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "get MYSINGLETON="+mysingleton);
        // need to convert mysingleton into a Bundle! - unfortunately no provided method!
        Bundle singleton_bundle = new Bundle(mysingleton);   <== NOT AVAILABLE
        if (singleton_bundle == null || ! instance.onRestoreInstanceState(singleton_bundle)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "UNABLE TO DECODE MYSINGLETON!");
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.w(TAG, "UNABLE TO GET MYSINGLETON FROM INTENT!");
    }
```

By implementing onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, those
methods can be reused to manage the singleton bundle.
But first you need to be able to convert the String to a Bundle!