# Byte Array to Bundle

Tags: android

I have a `Bundle` and I store it to the disk as a byte array. Now, when I retrieve it I take the byte array. How can I convert this again to `Bundle`?

```
byte fileContent[] =  new byte[(int)file.length()];
int numerOfReturnedbytes = 0;

try {
    //read the stream and set it into the byte array readFileByteArray
    //and returns the numerOfReturnedbytes. If returns -1 means that
    //that the end of the stream has been reached.
    numerOfReturnedbytes = fis.read(fileContent);
    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (numerOfReturnedbytes == -1) {
    return;
} else {
    //creating empty parcel object
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    //un-marshalling the data contained into the byte array  to the parcel
    parcel.unmarshall(fileContent, 0, numerOfReturnedbytes);
}
```

The `fileContent` is the byte array. Any ideas on how can I solve my problem?

Comment: i don't understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

To convert Bundle to ByteArray

```
    public byte[] bundleToBytes(@NonNull Bundle bundle) {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.writeBundle(bundle);
        byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
        parcel.recycle();
        return bytes;
    }
```

To convert ByteArray to Bundle

```
    @NonNull
    public Bundle bytesToBundle(byte[] bytes) {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.unmarshall(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        Bundle bundle = parcel.readBundle(ClassWithinProject.class.getClassLoader());
        parcel.recycle();
        return bundle;
    }
```

Comment: can we use just readBundle() instead readBundle(ClassLoader) ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. From the Android documentation:

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

This means, that after an OS upgrade the data written by your application could become unreadable.

Comment: What that means practically??And if should not do that, what I have to do?

Comment: You could write the elements of the bundle individually.

Comment: I need to keep the data in the memory only for a user's session. That means that I want it for a maximum of 15 minutes. Don't you think that in my occasion, this approach is useful?

Comment: In that case it may be safe to use.

Answer (score -1):

Would it be something like :

```
Bundle bundle = Bundle.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
```

once you have the parcel ?

## Edit

or is it

```
Bundle bundle = parcel.readParcelable(null);
```

? I don't remember. I'd read the documentation, but you know ...

(actually, i really don't know what is best, they appear to do pretty much the same thing)

## Edit 2

There is also

```
Bundle bundle = parcel.readBundle();
```

Amazing the quantity of information in the documentation thingy. I should go there more often.

Comment: not entirely sure how you actually create that file of yours, so, yes, this may be not exactly how it would work

Comment: incredible. how do you create the file in the first place ? would you mind sharing that ? knowing how a marshaling is done can, is some occasions, be useful when it comes to unmarshaling the data.

Comment: what you are looking for is marshall(), not createByteArray(). (the fact that you use unmarshall could have tiped you off).

Comment: Nothing is working. I will try to find another way without parcel. Thanks for yur help njzk2

Comment: `parcel.setDataPosition(0);` is an important step to do before you try to make a `Bundle` out of a `Parcel`.

Comment: @KamranAhmed only if you just created the parcel yourself. If you pass it to an Activity, for example, the Parcel is reset before being handed to you.